# sort files in descending alphabetical order

Tags: c

I am trying to modify this file https://github.com/HaarigerHarald/omxiv/blob/master/omxiv.c, I think it is function getImageFilesInDir. I need to change it so it will return back not files in directory in alphabetical ascending order but in alphabetical descending order (img05.png, img04.png, img03.png, img02.png, img01.png), so image viewer will show me the first image that file with the greatest number (in my case img05.png)

I tried something like `for(i=0; i-1; i--)` but it did not help.
Any idea please how to do it?

```
static int getImageFilesInDir(char ***list, const char* path){
    struct dirent **namelist;
    int imageNum;
    imageNum = scandir(path, &namelist, imageFilter, alphasort);
    if (imageNum < 0)
        return imageNum;
    else {
        *list=malloc(sizeof(char*) *imageNum);
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<imageNum; i++) {
            if(strcmp(path, ".") == 0 || strcmp(path, "./") == 0){
                (*list)[i]= malloc(strlen(namelist[i]->d_name)+1);
                strcpy((*list)[i], namelist[i]->d_name);
            }else{
                if(strrchr(path, '/')- path != strlen(path)-1){
                    (*list)[i]= malloc(strlen(path)+strlen(namelist[i]->d_name)+2);
                    strcpy((*list)[i],path);
                    (*list)[i][strlen(path)]='/';
                    strcpy((*list)[i]+strlen(path)+1,namelist[i]->d_name);
                }else{
                    (*list)[i]= malloc(strlen(path)+strlen(namelist[i]->d_name)+1);
                    strcpy((*list)[i],path);
                    strcpy((*list)[i]+strlen(path),namelist[i]->d_name);
                }
            }
            free(namelist[i]);
        }
        free(namelist);
    }
    return imageNum;
}
```

(This is my first touch with C)

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: You want to implement you own compare callback function replacing `alphasort`. RTFM for `scandir()`.

Comment: Or you could just invert the order of items in the returned namelist array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to give `scandir()` a compare callback that does the negative of what `alphasort()` does. You can literally just negate `alphasort()` output:

```
int descalphasort(const struct dirent **a, const struct dirent **b)
{
    return - alphasort(a, b);
}
```

Or as pointed out by @chux, invert the `alphasort()` parameters:

```
int descalphasort(const struct dirent **a, const struct dirent **b)
{
    return alphasort(b, a);
}
```

And use `descalphasort` on your `scandir()` call instead of `alphasort`.

Comment: How about `alphasort(b, a);`?